# c# do-while loop not working as I need it to

Tags: c#

I want my loop to repeat as long as width is under 0.5 (MIN_WIDTH) or above 5.0 (MAX_WIDTH) both are created as constant doubles.
When I write the number 0, it does repeat as it should, but if I write anything between 0.1 - 0.4 it skips the loop, why?

```
  do
        {
            Console.Write("Give the width of the window between " + MIN_WIDTH + " and " + MAX_WIDTH + " :");
            widthString = Console.ReadLine();
            width = double.Parse(widthString);
        } while (width < MIN_WIDTH || width > MAX_WIDTH);
```

Comment: Have you tried (if you are using VS) to debug the solution to check the value(s)?

Comment: @geostocker, I think the OP was pretty clear about how it's not working...  It skips the loop when he doesn't expect it to.

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint and check what the value of `width` is. My guess is your locale/culture settings don't match your input, so it parses `0.1` as `1` and `0.4` as `4`.

Comment: I tried that, and you're right. it sets width to 1 if I write 0.1. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you experience problems with *decimal* and *thousand* separators: if in your current culture (e.g. in Russian `RU-ru` one) `.` is a *thousand* (not *decimal*) separator it ignores and you'll get `0.4` -> `04` -> `4` which will *pass* the condition.

Remedy: specify `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` explictly

```
do {
  Console.Write($"Give the width of the window between {MIN_WIDTH} and {MAX_WIDTH}: ");
  widthString = Console.ReadLine();

  double width;

  if (!double.TryParse(widthString, 
                       NumberStyles.Any, 
                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                       out width))
    continue;
} while (width < MIN_WIDTH || width > MAX_WIDTH);
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the issue. I'll read some more about the "CultureInfo.InvariantCulture" part.